# how to perform a sum with laravel in an eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a detail table where there is a relationship with the product table, in the detail table I have a product_id field.

I try to multiply the quantity that appears in the detail table and the price that appears in the product table, used `DB ::raw` but I get a column error not found.

QueryScope in Detalle Model

```
 $query->with(['product' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'name', 'price');
        }])
        ->select('*', DB::raw('SUM(count*products.price) as fullcount'))
        ->groupBy('product_id');
```

Comment: what table/alias `count` column belongs to?

Comment: @Alex count in table details

Comment: I don't see any `details` table involved.

Comment: @Alex That queryScope is inside the model Details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
$query->select('product_id', DB::raw('SUM(count*products.price) as fullcount'))
    ->join('products', 'details.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->groupBy('product_id');
```

Comment: An additional query, what I want is that you group them if a field of the detail table has a certain value, otherwise you leave them separated Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so.